# In California, what claims may not state a dollar amount in a complaint or in its prayer?

Tags: california, civil-procedure, small-claims-court, pleadings

Punitive damages may not be claimed as an exact dollar figure in a complaint or in the prayer since the middle '80's in California, and must be left to the jury.

What other claims cannot be claimed as an exact dollar amount in a complaint or in its prayer?

Can you claim any form of pain & suffering (for i.e., physical pain, mental suffering, loss of quality of life, shock, anger, indignity, nervousness, embarrassment, indignity, emotional distress, depression, inconvenience, ordeal etc.)?

Since the fact-finder is the judge themselves, I wondered if any of these restrictions or prohibitions apply in small claims court as well?

---

Although I am personally more interested in California's regulation, if there are applicable answers to this question elsewhere, I would also be glad to read!